# CKEditor image preview

Tags: ckeditor

In the image plugin, before entering any image url you can observe some text in the 'Preview' window. And after inserting a valid image url, you can see the image in the preview window but the text is still present below the image preview. Any specific reason behind this? 
Also, do I have the permission to remove this text?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a legacy thing from the days of using the editor to set the image alignment. It's there to show you how it is positions around text or whatever you are placing your image before.

It is confusing though and to remove it you need to add this to your config:

`config.image_previewText = ' ';`

I found you have to set it to an empty space rather than an empty string else it defaults to lorem ipsum.